# 404 Response with Retrofit POST request with Headers parameters

Tags: android, header, retrofit2, response

I am new to Retrofit Library. When I sending post request with headers parameters using hashMap using `@HeaderMap` annotation.

Below is my code

```
 @POST(Constants.UrlPath.POST_CLOSE_EVENT)
Call<ResponseBody> callDeleteEventRequest(@HeaderMap Map <String, String>id);
```

I am sending the headers using `HashMap` here like this.

```
 HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                 headers.put("eventId", String.valueOf(1));
```

I am getting 404 error response. Please some one help me.
I have reviewed some Stack Overflow links, but again I am getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Constants.UrlPath.POST_CLOSE_EVENT)
Call<ResponseBody> callDeleteEventRequest(@FieldMap Map <String, String>id);
```

Comment: I donr have any body parameters here.. However If I try this, I am getting some error

Answer (score 0):

add headers in your interface class:

```
 @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json",
        "eventId: 1"})
@POST(Constants.UrlPath.POST_CLOSE_EVENT)
Call<ResponseBody> callDeleteEventRequest();
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193811/discussion-between-basha-and-sandeep-malik).

Answer (score 0):

check your path `Constants.UrlPath.POST_CLOSE_EVENT` is right or not.
try to call using **postman** if it is working fine in that or not.